# Configuring mongodb and inserting a JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

**Background:**
I am a beginner in both Node.js and Mongodb. I'v been following a tutorial to just setup mongodb with node.js locally to practice inserting/deleting.

**What i am trying to accomplish:**
I just want to be able to create a db, insert the following 'object' and print it out from db to confirm it worked.

**What i have tried**

```
var url = "TheDatabase";
var collections = ["Location"];
var mongojs = require("mongojs")
var db = mongojs(url, collections);

var object = {
    "place" : {
        "address" : "123 road",
        "code" : "ABC CDE",
        "letters" : "AA",
        "coord" : [  99.55, -20.5 ]
    },
    "keyword1" : "World",
    "keyword2" : "Biomech",
    "keyword3" : "Spotify",
    "_id" : "1"
}

db.collection.save(doc);
```

So i learned about mongojs, and followed a tutorial here. 
http://howtonode.org/node-js-and-mongodb-getting-started-with-mongojs

```
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);
```

This  line didnt work for me in the tutorial so i replaced it with the following

```
var mongojs = require("mongojs")
var db = mongojs(url, collections);
```

then i discovered [Collection.save()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html) and thought that might work to save the object?

**Edit**

So i have discovered db.Location.save(object) but now i receive this error

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\..\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:236
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the save method on the name of the collection.

```
db.Location.save(object)
```

Comment: After adding that line i get this error

C:\Users\user\Desktop\..\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:236
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)

Comment: Are you running mongodb server?

Comment: Alternatively you can change url. Try var url = 'localhost:27017/TheDatabase'

Comment: I started mongodb server and that fixed it. Thanks.
Would you be able to help me retrieve this data from the db and print it?

Comment: Although I can but I suggest you must try that on your own to learn mongodb. It is very easy. If you get into some problem SO community is always there. :)